# How to execute code in a new browser tab in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, browser

I already have code that opens a new tab in selenium, python:

```
class misc_selenium:

def __init__(self, driver):
    self.driver = driver


def open_new_tab(self, url, client=None):

    self.driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{url}", "_blank");''')
```

However after I execute further selenium it still executes it in my new tab. How do I make selenium execute it in the newly opened tab?

Comment: Off the top of my head, selenium has a functionality called "windows" that are identified by handles. See https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```py
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

to switch to the new tab, and then execute a script:

```py
driver.execute_script('''navigator.userAgent''')
```